# How to echo PHP session variable While using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

I am new in PHP. I have a file upload code. This code upload file and save it in Mysql db. In this code i use Two fields One is Date and Second is title. Date and Title is also stored in db when user click on submit button. I use Jquery in my code to pick current date and display calendar. My Jquery functionality is that In Date Field it display current date. When i change the date in Date Field it also automatically change the date in title field.

Here is my Problem.

I use session in my code and echo session variable in Title field. As i told above my Jquery functionallty. I face problem while changing date.

When i change date in Date field it does not display session variable data.

Here is pic without change in date

[image: witout change]

Here is pic after change in date [image]

I want that when i change date it also display all other variable data.

Here is my Session Code

```
<?php

 // starts session

 session_start();

 // setting variable values during session

$_SESSION['UserName']='Saqib';
$_SESSION['TeamName']='MIT';
?>
```

Here is my file code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <form action="up_mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <table width="547" class="tblbdr" >
    <tr>
        <td height="23"  colspan="6" class="head"><p>  Morning Briefing </p></td>
</tr>
 <tr> <td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Date:</b> </td> <td><input name="mydate" type="text" id="mydate" style="width:200px"> </td></tr>
<tr>

<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Title: </b><br> </td> 

<td class="celltext" style="width:200px" >  <span id="dt_title"> <input name="title" type="text" value=" MB | 
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['UserName'];?> | <?php echo $_SESSION['TeamName'];?> | <?php echo date("d-M-y");?>" 
data-title="MB | " style="width:200px"/> </span> </td> </tr>

</tr>
<td class="celltext"><b>Upload File:</b></td>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" width="100%" size=80/>

   <!-- <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple style="width:300px"/> -->
   </td></tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/> </td> <td> </td>
    <td width="151">

   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="12">
    </td>
    <td width="290">

   </td> </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing to do is get those `<tr>...</tr>` and `<td>...</td>` tags in balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change 'data-title' attribute in 'input' field

```
data-title="MB | <?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'];?> | <?php echo $_SESSION['TeamName'];?> | "
```

instead of

```
data-title="MB | "
```

Answer (score 1):

put session_start() at first line before doctype html.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but YES, I was about to make the same point (in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is update your `onSelect` to also contain the contents of your PHP session data. I.e:

```
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']) + " | <?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'].' | '.$_SESSION['TeamName']; ?>").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
```

Not sure if I got the values right there (or the syntax) but you can probably take it the rest of the way if I'm following correctly. Let me know via comments!

Comment: When i replace by your code. My date function not working. It show mw blank date field

Comment: @chords please see where have you added Session variables. You added it in selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Change your scritp to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            changeDate =$("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title');
            sessions = "<?php echo $_SESSION['UserName']; ?> | <?php echo $_SESSION['TeamName']; ?> | ";
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val(changeDate+sessions+dateText);
       }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

Also You dont need to open `session_start()` again on `<span id="dt_title">`.

Comment: can u check with `alert()` or `console.log()` what variable isnt working? I dont have a sample to try here. changeDate or sessions.

Comment: I am new born in php. I dont have any idea. How i can do it? That is why i post my question for help

Comment: Its javascript.(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) or (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just append your session data in textfield as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+"| <?php echo $_SESSION['UserName'] | $_SESSION['TeamName']; ?> | "+dateText);
}
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```